# Retrofit Body isn't showing desired response from Nested JSON

Tags: java, json, android-studio, retrofit, pojo

[image: Edited in picture for debug]I've been trying to connect an Android App to the Fitbit API using Retrofit however I'm struggling with getting a connection to a JSON with a nested user section. I've managed to get the classes set up however get Body: com.example.myapplication.User@6fe68c1 when requesting the body back.

Whilst learning about Retrofit I've had no problems with using  however this seems to be different because of the "user" in the JSON.

Shortened JSON I'm working from

```
{
    "user": {
        "age": 23,
        "avatar": "https://static0.fitbit.com/images/profile/defaultProfile_100.png",
        "averageDailySteps": 2673,
        "dateOfBirth": "1999-01-25",
        "displayName": "Name.",
        "features": {
            "exerciseGoal": true
        },
        "fullName": "Full Name",
        "gender": "MALE",
        "glucoseUnit": "METRIC",
        "height": 180.3,
        "memberSince": "2022-02-28",
        "startDayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
        "strideLengthRunning": 123.10000000000001,
        "weight": 72.5,
    }
}
```

Fitbit Class

```
    imports
    
    @Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
    public class Fitbit {
    
        @SerializedName("user")
        @Expose
        private User user;
    
        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }
    
        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }
    
    }
```

User Class

```
imports

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class User {

    @SerializedName("age")
    @Expose
    private Integer age;
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    @Expose
    private String avatar;
    @SerializedName("averageDailySteps")
    @Expose
    private Integer averageDailySteps;
    @SerializedName("dateOfBirth")
    @Expose
    private String dateOfBirth;
    @SerializedName("fullName")
    @Expose
    private String fullName;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    private String gender;
    @SerializedName("height")
    @Expose
    private Double height;
    @SerializedName("memberSince")
    @Expose
    private String memberSince;
    @SerializedName("startDayOfWeek")
    @Expose
    private String startDayOfWeek;
    @SerializedName("strideLengthRunning")
    @Expose
    private Double strideLengthRunning;
    @SerializedName("strideLengthWalking")
    @Expose
    private Double strideLengthWalking;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    @Expose
    private String timezone;
    @SerializedName("waterUnitName")
    @Expose
    private String waterUnitName;
    @SerializedName("weight")
    @Expose
    private Double weight;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public Integer getAverageDailySteps() {
        return averageDailySteps;
    }

    public void setAverageDailySteps(Integer averageDailySteps) {
        this.averageDailySteps = averageDailySteps;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getMemberSince() {
        return memberSince;
    }

    public void setMemberSince(String memberSince) {
        this.memberSince = memberSince;
    }

    public String getStartDayOfWeek() {
        return startDayOfWeek;
    }

    public void setStartDayOfWeek(String startDayOfWeek) {
        this.startDayOfWeek = startDayOfWeek;
    }

    public Double getStrideLengthRunning() {
        return strideLengthRunning;
    }

    public void setStrideLengthRunning(Double strideLengthRunning) {
        this.strideLengthRunning = strideLengthRunning;
    }

    public Double getStrideLengthWalking() {
        return strideLengthWalking;
    }

    public void setStrideLengthWalking(Double strideLengthWalking) {
        this.strideLengthWalking = strideLengthWalking;
    }

    public String getTimezone() {
        return timezone;
    }

    public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    public String getWaterUnitName() {
        return waterUnitName;
    }

    public void setWaterUnitName(String waterUnitName) {
        this.waterUnitName = waterUnitName;
    }

    public Double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

JsonPlaceholderAPI Interface Class

```
imports

public interface JsonPlaceholderAPI {

    @Headers({"Authorization: Bearer bearercodeinserted"})
    @GET("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json")
    Call<User> getUser();
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textViewResult;

private JsonPlaceholderAPI jsonPlaceholderAPI;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    jsonPlaceholderAPI = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderAPI.class);
    getUser();
}

private void getUser() {

    Call<User> call = jsonPlaceholderAPI.getUser();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }

            textViewResult.setText("Body: " + response.body());

            }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error code?
Perhaps the cause of the error is that you added not existing fields such as `waterUnitName`. Try to remove all non-existing fields and repeat the request.

Comment: Hi! The error is that the resulted output of the code is coming up as Body: com.example.myapplication.User@6fe68c1 instead of the list of data from the JSON itself

Comment: And you expect an object according to your code `Call<User> getUser();`. If you want a list then wrap User with List e.g. `Call<List<User>> getUser();`

Comment: Just tried that unfortunately I got "Expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path $" from the response

Comment: Is it this `textViewResult.setText("Body: " + response.body());` gives you `Body: com.example.myapplication.User@6fe68c1`? If yes, this is correct result.
If you want to get each fields to be represented on your textView you have to override `toString()` on your `User` object.

Comment: The textViewResult.setText("Body: " + response.body()); is indeed what gives the Body: com.example.myapplication.User@6fe68c1. What would I need to change in order to override toString on the User object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Change `Call<User>()` to `Call<Fitbit>()`
and `response.body().getUser().toString()`

If you want `textViewResult.setText("Body: " + response.body());` to give you string representation of your User data you have to override `toString()` function on your User object. For example:

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("age")
    @Expose
    ...

    @Override
    String toString() {
       return "age: " + age + " avatar: " + avatar + ....;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just tried this unfortunately I got a response of "age: null" on my Textview

Comment: Perhaps your age is null from the server side. To be sure put break point on your ` textViewResult.setText("Body: " + response.body());
` line and debug it. You will be able to see User data values.
Here is an example how to do it https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-debugging-with-breakpoints#2

Comment: How strange, I got the response of 
Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json}
body = {User@16982} "age: null"
 age = null
 avatar = null
 / remaining fields = null

Comment: Can you include a screen of this on your question above?

Comment: Just added it to the main post! :)

Comment: It means the problem is somewhere else. Why you have `@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")` on User class? I think it is redundant. Can you show your Retrofit creation?

Comment: According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-exclude-a-field-from-json-using-expose-annotation-in-java source, `@Expose` is used to exclude fields from JSON. If you remove it your code may work.

Comment: Just tried that too, unfortunately no change in the null sectors

Comment: Have you tried to do the same exact request with postman? Are you sure that your server returns you anything with the same request?

Comment: I've tried with the curl originally provided and it returns a JSON with all values of the authorization codes user

Comment: Share how you create Retrofit object pls.

Comment: Just added it to the main post under the part I had originally commented

Comment: Change `Call<User>()` to `Call<Fitbit>()`

Comment: Just tried that and we're back to the Body com.example.myapplication.Fitbit@c93def5

Comment: Body().getUser().toString()

Comment: If that does not help try with debug.